# Post the data failed in php

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, post

I have some trouble during post my data, show 500 internal server error.
So, I think it must be unsyncronize between client side and server side. I have check but I dont have any clue.This the following php script:

```
<input type="text" id="use" name="use">
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass"></td>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="logaccept">

if ($("#passlog").valid()){
                                var params = $("#passlog").serialize();
                                $.ajax({
                                         type:"post",
                                         url:"process3.php",
                                         data:params,
                                         cache:false,
                                         async:false,
                                         success: function(data){
                                               //do something
                                                }
                                         });
                                   }
```

This the server side:

```
switch(postVar('action')) {
              case 'logaccept' :
                passlog(postVar('use'),postVar('pass'));
                break;
}

function passlog($use,$pass){
        $Use = mysql_real_escape_string($use);
        $Pass= mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

//build query
        $sql = "SELECT Privilege FROM admin WHERE user='".$Use."' AND password='".$Pass."'";
echo $sql;
$data=mysql_query($sql) or die(_ERROR26.": ".mysql_error());
if($data){
                $priv = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
}else{
                        echo 0; // If login fails
                        }

?> //show Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /var/www/html/process3.php on line 74
```

Could you tell me what's wrong with my script?

Comment: Please check webserver's error_log file and show us the error that is there

Comment: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`.like this?

Comment: No, I think this is the error you are receiving on the client side (ie - the browser) - we need the error message from the server. The error_log file on my CentOs server is located at /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: I'm use tail /var/log/apache2/error.log:`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /var/www/html/process3.php on line 76`,it's below `?>`

Comment: how stupid are me, after add `}` before `?>` it can work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in file process3.php - thats why you get the internal server error - that is the first thing you have to correct